# Creating a Form that lets the user review what they entered before submission

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle-apex

I am trying to create a Form that lets the user to review what they entered before submitting the form. The first page will let the user enter what they want. The second page will show what the user entered. The second page will have two buttons. one for make changes and the second would be for submit. The third page will be the final summary page and will let the user print the form.

What i tried:

I created all the fields on first 1 page manually and then passed everything to page 2. I created a branch on page 1 to pass the values to page 2. Page 2 was connected to the table in which all the information is stored in. Page 2 had two buttons. One button was to make changes to page 1 and second button was to submit. Page 3 was just a summary page which allowed the user to print. It worked nicely but i later realized that if someone used a comma or pressed enter to start a new line in one of the fields then it will give me errors. This problem was occurring because i used a branch.

What i want to do.

I created a temp_table which is exactly like the main_table. The first page will be connected to the temp_table. The second page will be connected to a view on temp_table to show what the user entered. Page 2 will have two buttons called make changes and submit. Make changes will take the user to page 1 so the user can edit what they entered. Submit button will transfer what the user entered from temp_table to main_table (I believe we can use a process that runs a query to transfer data to main_table whenever the user presses submit). page 3 will be just a summary page that will let the user make changes.

I don't know how to approach this. How do i make the Make Changes button work? Any advise?

Note: I am very new to apex so i apologize if i made any mistake.

Thank you and any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Why you want save data to any temp table? on first page you submit data to session by button click and branch to 2 page (no need pass values, they in session state after "submit"). In 2 page, you just need get values from items on 1 page, for example display only item P2_USER_INPUT_TEXT Source Type = Item (application or page item name)  P1_USER_INPUT_TEXT.

Comment: yes you are right @АнатолийПредеин. Using temp table was the wrong way to approach this problem. I just ended up using only one page. The page turns into read-only when the user presses the Review button. Then Two Buttons appear called edit and submit. Edit allows you to go back into edit mode and submit just triggers a sql query to insert all the item data to a table. I used the Request value to turn the page into read only and make the buttons appear and disappear.